# beautifulsoup does not find all p with a certain class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to find all p in a certain html page I saved locally.
My code is

```
with open ("./" + str(filename) + ".txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
t11 = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "commentsParagraph"})
```

this codes works for part of the page, but some part of the page is loaded with ajax (which I preloaded before I saved the source), and the code is not working on it.

to test this I added to one of the `p` tags in the ajax portion the class `commentsParagraph2`, and changed my code to

```
t11 = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "commentsParagraph2"})
```

but t11 is an empty list.

I am attaching the page file as well[here](https://justpaste.it/z64t)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing that Ajax response stuff you are preloading is not being seen by beautifulsoup as part of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one p tag with the commentsParagraph2 class in your html which bs4 can find without issue using all three parsers:

```
In [8]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: soup1 = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/padraic
   ...: /t.html").read(),"html5lib")
   ...: soup2 = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/padraic
   ...: /t.html"),"html.parser")
   ...: soup3 = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/padraic
   ...: /t.html"),"lxml")
   ...: print(soup1.select_one("p.commentsParagraph2"))
   ...: print(soup2.select_one("p.commentsParagraph2"))
   ...: print(soup3.select_one("p.commentsParagraph2"))
   ...: 
<p class="commentsParagraph2">
So much better than Ryder. Only take Econ 11 if she's one of the professors teaching it. Beware her tests though, which are much different from Ryder's.
</p>
<p class="commentsParagraph2">
So much better than Ryder. Only take Econ 11 if she's one of the professors teaching it. Beware her tests though, which are much different from Ryder's.
</p>
<p class="commentsParagraph2">
So much better than Ryder. Only take Econ 11 if she's one of the professors teaching it. Beware her tests though, which are much different from Ryder's.
</p>
```

So either you are using the broken and no longer maintained *BeautifulSoup3* or an older version of bs4.

Comment: I am using from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
how can i check the version?

Comment: `import bs4;bs4.__version__`

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: 4.5.1, what do you have?

Comment: '4.3.2'
 tried pip install but it won't update it on my mac

Comment: `pip install -U bs4`?

Comment: Downloading bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from bs4)
Installing collected packages: bs4
  Running setup.py install for bs4 ... done
Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1

>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__version__
'4.3.2'

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: python version : 2.7.12

Comment: What does `which -a python2` output?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
/usr/local/bin/python2

Comment: Run `/usr/local/bin/python2  -m pip install -U bs4`

Answer (score -1):

I have downloaded you html and done some tests, the beautifulsoup module could only find out three p nodes. And I guess, that's because there is some iframes in the html, so BS does not work probably. My suggestion is using `re` module instead of `bs`

sample code for your reference:

```
import re

with open('1.html', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    m=re.findall(r'(?<=<p class="commentsParagraph">)[\!\w\s.\'\,\-\(\)\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\+\=\/|\^<]+(?=</p>)', data)
    print(m)
```